# Google Apps Document onOpen not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am attempting to create a google document that autofills author, document name, date created and date modified as per a Word doc.

I have a script that is functioning when I run in the script editor and when I trigger via an added menu item but will not trigger onOpen.

This is how I am accessing the info:

```
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var bodyText = body.editAsText();
  var docID = document.getId();
  var docName = document.getName();
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(docID);
  var docCreated = file.getDateCreated().toString();
  var docUpdated = file.getLastUpdated().toString();
```

I then just do some find replace in the document. Nothing seems to run after

```
var docName = document.getName();
```

Does the getName() method need to be triggered? I want to avoid users having to click a button to update the document.

Appreciate any assistance.

Mitch

Answer (score 1):

You can check the execution transcript of your `onOpen()` trigger function by opening the Script Editor shortly after opening the document, the selecting "View - Execution Transcript".

In there, you'll find something like this:

```
[13-08-01 11:53:18:163 EDT] Document.getName() [0 seconds]
[13-08-01 11:53:18:203 EDT] Execution failed: No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 41, file "Code") [0.052 seconds total runtime]
```

According to [Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers), simple triggers are not supposed to allow execution of services that require authentication. That restriction wouldn't seem to apply to `Document.getName()`, especially after `Document.getId()` has successfully worked. An issue exists for this, visit [Issue 3083](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3083) and star it to vote & receive updates.

You'll find similar problems with your DocsList method calls, however they are not covered under the [Google Apps Script Security Model](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_google_accounts#securityModel), so it's not surprising that they get blocked.

As a work-around, you could have your `onOpen()` remind the user to set the document variables, until they've done so.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Set variables', 'setVars')
      .addToUi();

  var doneFirstRun = ScriptProperties.getProperty('doneFirstRun');
  if (doneFirstRun == null) {
    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    ui.alert( "Set document variables\n\n"
             +"Select Menu - Set variables");
  }
}

function setVars() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = document.getBody();
  var bodyText = body.editAsText();
  var docID = document.getId();
  var url = document.getUrl();
  var docName = document.getName();     // Does not work in onOpen
  var editors = document.getEditors();  // Does not work in onOpen
  var viewers = document.getViewers();  // Does not work in onOpen
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(docID);
  var docCreated = file.getDateCreated().toString();
  var docUpdated = file.getLastUpdated().toString();  

  // ... do actual work here

  // Completed setting document variables - disable reminder.
  var doneFirstRun = ScriptProperties.setProperty('doneFirstRun',true);

  ui.alert("Completed");  
}
```