# Google Apps Script : Making an A Function Execute on Open

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I found a script that will move my spreadsheet to a folder. How can I make it so that the functions runs when the spreadsheet is open. I will be applying this to a template so that everytime the template is opened, the "Copy of " spreadsheet file will automatically be moved to my Packing Lists folder.

Here's the code I have....

```
function MoveFileTo()  
{

    var docs=DocsList.find('Save Test'); 
    var doc=docs[0];   /*Since we assume there is only one file with the name "Hello World",  we take the index 0 */
    var folders = doc.getParents(); 
    var newFolder=DocsList.getFolder('Packing Lists');
    doc.addToFolder(newFolder); // This will add the document to its new location.
    var docParentFolder=folders[0]; 
    doc.removeFromFolder(docParentFolder); // This will remove the document from its original location. 
}
```

EDIT: I tried changing function MoveFileTo to `onOpen()` and `onEdit()` but it doesn't seem to work properly. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158179/google-apps-document-onopen-not-working. You may find your answer there in the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try use driveapp instead of doclist (it's deprecated). the impinball comment is really usefull, you should have a look at it.
Anyway here a working code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID_WHERE8YOU_WANT_TO_MOVE_YOUR_FILES");
  var fileList = DriveApp.searchFiles("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and title contains 'FILE_TITLE'"); // change this search if necessary
  var originalFileId="THE_ID_OF_THE_ACTUAL_SPREADSHEET_TO_BE_EXCLUDED_FROM_THE_SCRIPT_TREATMENT";
  while(fileList.hasNext()){
    var fileToMove = fileList.next();
    if(fileToMove.getId()==originalFileId){
      continue; // don't do anything if it's the original file
    }
    var papas = fileToMove.getParents();
    destFolder.addFile(fileToMove); // do the job
    while(papas.hasNext()){
      papas.next().removeFile(fileToMove); // remove the actuals parents (can be more than one)
    }
  }
}
```